# how can we find omega limit set in symbolic space

Tags: dynamical-systems

let $f:\sum_{2}^+ \to  \sum_{2}^+ $ given by $f(a_0 a_1 a_2...)=0 a_0 a_1 a_2...$.

what type of elements are in $\sum_{2}^+$?

How can we find the omega limit set of each point in $\sum_{2}^+$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You ask "What type of elements are in $\sum_2^+$?" You should look at the definition of that object.

Comment: I have seen definition. As here we are taking$ s=2 $ , so it means partition set contains just $2$ elements,i.e., $0,1$. but, in the map, there are different type of co,ordinates. How, we are taking different type of co-ordinates?

Comment: *You* have seen the definition. That's perfect. But how can other people guess it? Without giving the context, you cannot expect others to be able to help you.